# Android Loading Dialog Freez

Tags: android

I have this code in android. But when the Thread begging the loading in freezing. How can I prevent this freezing happens. Here is the code related the issue:

```
private void reload(final String criteria) {
        try {
myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myfiles.this,
     "Please wait...", "Loading Your Photos... Please Wait",
     false);

   new Thread() {
    public void run() {
     try {

      Thread.sleep(2000);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       // Fetch the fact

       try {
        /* here my code  */

       } catch (Exception e) {
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

      }
     });
     // Dismiss the Dialog

     myProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
   }.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

It would be great if someone can check

Answer (score 0):

By using runOnUiThread you are doing your intensive load task on the UI thread which will freeze the UI.  You want to run your task in a background thread, and then on task completion update the ui.

```
Thread task = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
       //load some data.
       // notify UI thread using Handler
    }
});
task.start();
```